# JQuery function returning before $.each complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

This script is part of a chrome extension that will loop through a table, look for a match, and send a message back to a background script. Here is the script (content script):

```
function resolveMulti(city){
  counter = 1;
  results = "";
  resultsArray = $("iFrame").contents().find("#table tr[id*='row'] td:nth-child(13)");
  resultsArray.each(function(index){
    if($(this).html().toLowerCase() == city.toLowerCase()){
      results = "Found";
    }
    else if(counter == resultsArray.length){
      results = "No City Match Found";
    }
    counter++;
  });
  return results;
}
```

The function is returning prior to the $.each loop finishing. Since 'results' isn't defined until the $.each loop is evaluated, the browser raises an error that 'results' hasn't been defined. How can I return the correct results from this function?

Comment: Consider adding `var results;` to the beginning of `resolveMulti(city)` as you are currently implicitly using a global.

Comment: Yo yo `:)` checkout the scope of your `results` var; how about `var results`

Comment: If `resultsArray` is an empty jQuery object, then `results` will never be set either because the `.each()` loop will never be executed.  And, if course, as others have said, you MUST make `results` and `resultsarray` and `counter` be local variables (use `var` in front of them to declare them) and probably should initialize 'results` with a default value.  Or, if you are in strict mode, then it's a script error to assign to a variable that has not been previously declared.

Comment: You all are 100% correct. Results should be initialized beforehand. Still, this is not the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your questions, then some notes about several issues in that code.

> The function is returning prior to the $.each loop finishing.

No, it isn't. It may be raising an exception, which is similar but different.

> Since 'results' isn't defined until the $.each loop is evaluated, the browser raises an error that 'results' hasn't been defined. How can I return the correct results from this function?

By declaring the variable. You need a `var results` in the function:

```
function resolveMulti(city){
  var results; // <=========== Here
  counter = 1;
  resultsArray = $("iFrame").contents().find("#table tr[id*='row'] td:nth-child(13)");
  resultsArray.each(function(index){
    if($(this).html().toLowerCase() == city.toLowerCase()){
      results = "Found";
    }
    else if(counter == resultsArray.length){
      results = "No City Match Found";
    }
    counter++;
  });
  return results;
}
```

Without one, in loose mode you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) (in strict mode, it would be an error). But the Horror of Implicit Globals only works for *setting*; if it happens that there are no matches for that jQuery selector, you'll never set anything, and so never create the global, and your `return` will try to *read* the value of an undefined symbol, which will cause a `ReferenceError` even in loose mode.

It's hard to tell from the snippet shown, but you may well have other undeclared variables in there (`counter` and `resultsArray`) that you want to declare with `var`.

But there's another issue: Your `results` variable will have the result from the *last* iteration of the `each` loop, overwriting any value from a previous iteration. And if there are no matching elements at all, it will never have a value. I suspect you wanted something like this:

```
function resolveMulti(city){
  var results = "No City Match Found";
  var resultsArray = $("iFrame").contents().find("#table tr[id*='row'] td:nth-child(13)");
  resultsArray.each(function(index){
    if($(this).html().toLowerCase() == city.toLowerCase()){
      results = "Found";
      return false; // <== Stops the `each` loop
    }
  });
  return results;
}
```

Comment: @TCrowder I tried your solution (which nonetheless, is far more elegant than mine), but now all results are showing up as "No City Match". Even if we place a console.log within the loop, it doesn't show before the background script continues (which occurs as a result to this function returning).

Comment: @ZAR: That tells you there are no matches for the selector. Do you really have an element with the `id` value `"table"`, for instance? `#table` looks for an element with that `id`, not a `table` element.

Comment: @TCrowder, This is slightly embarrasing. #table was just a proforma id name that I used in my example in place of the actual. Of course your response didn't work, I didn't change it back... Do these sorts of idiotic mistakes happen to everyone?? Thank you!

Comment: @ZAR: LOL I take it you mean it *did* work. :-) And yes, they do. Best,